# make file to write all information from serialPort

Tags: c, file, serial-port, file-descriptor

Firstly,  my "C code" listens serial Port all the time so
I want to make file and writes all data which I receives from serial Port. and I have a question: Is there any  necessary condition which file will be best or what  file Extension will be better, or is there any good rules, advice?

Comment: File extensions doesn’t affect anything. Just write the data anyway you want and set whatever file extension.

Comment: thank you. so I think .txt is the easiest solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with that file afterward and the information transmitted by the serial port.

Using a text file is easy and is often enough for a lot of situation, in particular if the objective is to keep a log.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm

Comment: no log is the other thing what i need, log is different. I just want to save this return data and then just to read. So, Anyway, thank you, I will try just .txt, and not  other particular things :)))

Comment: In that case, what Fedrik said is right, you don't even need an extension to your file.

Comment: The ".txt" would just allow that if you have your file on a computer, that it get automatically opened in a text editor directly (no need to select the application). It is useful in the case where the data is a text (the data is in ascii) that you need to record. But in your case this doesn't seem to matter.